# C# custom GUI, better implementation?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I'm making a custom GUI for my application. Basically my application has multiple 'tabs'. Each tab has a panel control binded to it, to display tabs contents. Whenever any of the tabs are clicked, appropriate panel control becomes visible (that displays contents) and the rest of the panels become invisible.

The problem is that when I design them in Visual Studio, it's hard to work, ether panels are stacked up on each other or I put them in different coordinates, and when panel becomes active, it's location is updated.

Is there I way I could design all the panels, like on separate 'form' or something like the same way I have separate classes? if that makes sense. Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I can't use the standard tab control, because my application has custom GUI, all buttons and everything is designed in image processing app. Tab control doesn't allow me to use my own graphics.

I'm going to take a look at UserControl, thanks everybody!

Comment: May I ask what's wrong with the standard `TabControl`?

Comment: Have you considered using custom controls instead of panels? Should provide the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create each tab content in a separate UserControl. Use that each UserControl as the only content on each tab.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to design each "panel" as a separate [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx).

Your main Form can just be composed from those UserControls, instead of having the entire UI built into one class.

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest you stick with the standard .NET controls in most cases. Particularly in this case the standard `TabControl` seems to be a good fit.

That said, you can place all the panels on the form in their final location (being sure not to place a panel within the other panel). You can then use the drop down in the Properties dialog to select the `Panel` you wish to work with. Next go to the **Format** menu and choose **Order**->**Bring to Front**. This will bring the wanted panel to the front so you may use the designer on it. You can then continue to hide or show the appropriate panels at runtime.